# It's posible export some databases Mysql using SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

I want export some databases using SSH

Example

> mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p database1 databse2 databse3 > dump.sql

It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` allows you to specify a command to execute on the remote system. So you can do this:

```
ssh user@remotehost mysqldump ... > dump.sql
```

And that would run the `mysqldump` (or any other command you put there) on the remote server and save its contents to dump.sql on your local computer.

You can specify the database you export with the `--databases` option:

```
mysqldump [options] --databases db1 [db2 db3 ...]
```

Comment: I want to export five databases but do not want to export all

Comment: @KedinnTurpo see the update in the answer, if you haven't already.